# What will be XPath of following XML?

Tags: xml, xpath

I have the following XML. What will be the XPath for "some text here" ?

```
<a:a>
    <a:b>
        <a:c>
            <x:d>
                <y id="z">
                    <myText> some text here </myText>
                </y>
            <x:d>
        </a:c>
    </a:b>
</a:a>
```

I need the exact XPath till "some text here".

Comment: I improved formatting and some capitalization. Also note that `<x:d>` has no closing tag, so the XML is not well-formed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To select the text-node which contains "some text here" use the following XPath:

```
a:a/a:b/a:c/x:d/y[@id = 'z']/myText/text()
```

Here the text still contains the leading and trailing spaces. To get rid of them apply the XPath-function [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions) to the expression:

```
normalize-space(a:a/a:b/a:c/x:d/y[@id = 'z']/myText/text())
```

Also make sure that namespaces are properly set. For testing I changed the first tag of your XML sample to

```
<a:a xmlns:a="http://a.com" xmlns:x="http://x.com">
  ...
</a:a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following xPath query: `//myText/text()`.

And, as a bonus, with XSLT you can use the template `<xsl:template match="myText">` in combination with a `value-of` selector:

```
<xsl:template match="myText">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>
```